# "Program has exited with status 101"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Can someone give me a bit more information on this error please?

Console only logs
Program exited with status value:101.

If you imagine I have a nsmutablearray:

[image]

It holds TimeEntry objects:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Constants.h"

/*
#define KTimeEntryInformationKey @"TEInformation"
#define KTimeEntryFromKey @"TEFrom"
#define KTimeEntryToKey @"TETo"
*/

@interface TimeEntry : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding> {

    NSDate *from;
    NSDate *to;

    NSString *information;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *from;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *to;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *information;

@end
```

The app gives me the error only when I add 15-20+ TimeEntry objects to the array and gives me the error when the above viewController (pictured) is popped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's the result code when your program is automatically closed for using too much memory.

It's not a true crash, so it won't stop execution or invoke gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jerbeers on Apple Discussion Boards:

101 is a memory error, something is causing it to run out of memory. You might try restarting the device and then run instruments and see what is happening. That way you can be sure an issue isn't left over from prior applications or versions you ha

And I fixed my App!!!! wooohooo! I'd left of the cellidentifier from the XIB. Scrolling through the table was allocating too much memory.. and Boom crash weirdness.